# How to select all in WHERE IN if parameter value is null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So, I have a stored procedure which receives a list of IDs, or no IDs at all.
If procedure receives no IDs, the select should return all rows as if WHERE IN isn't even there.

I've tried the following but I get a query with very long execution duration so clearly I'm not doing it right. Here's what I've tried.

```
-- some select
WHERE someId IN
(CASE
    WHEN @list IS NOT NULL
        THEN (SELECT col1 FROM fnIdArrayToTable (@list,','))
    ELSE
        someId
END)
```

Note: fnIdArrayToTable takes multiple IDs and returns a table containing those IDs

Comment: Erland has a wealth of information about [dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html); the other parts are worth reading as well.

Comment: You could make two sprocs, one without the @list parameter, one with, and redirect accordingly in the business logic, either in the application, or in a wrapper sproc (in case you do not want to change the application code).

Comment: Thank you Milan, I've made two sprocs as you suggested and wrapped them in another sproc. It works great :)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying `exists`:

```
where @list is null or
      exists (select 1
              from fnIdArrayToTable(@list, ',') l
              where l.col1 = ?.someId
             )
```

Note:  I don't know what your function is doing, so it might be impossible to speed up.

Assuming you have no duplicates in `@list`, then it might be better to move the logic to the `from` clause:

```
select . . .
from t left join
     fnIdArrayToTable(@list, ',') l
     on t.someid = l.col1
where l.col1 is not null or @list is null'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, execution time is still very long... Is my where equal to your suggestions in terms of results it should return? I don't know if this info helps, but function fnIdArrayToTable takes multiple IDs and makes a table containing those IDs.